# homestead vagrant broken after added new site

Tags: vagrant, homestead

I got a strange issue with my vagrant box. I am  not very familiar with vagrant. Just want to check if any one has fixed the same problem or at least can shed some light to me.  Thanks in advance for your help!

The box was working fine until I have added a new laravel site into it.(I didn't change anything from the vagrantfile. Only added the sites maping for the new site) After composer install, I tried to reload vagrant box. Then I got error as:

```
Bins:homestead Leo$ vagrant reload
/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/homestead/vendor/laravel/homestead/scripts/homestead.rb:178:in `+': no implicit conversion of nil into String (TypeError)
    from /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/homestead/vendor/laravel/homestead/scripts/homestead.rb:178:in `block (2 levels) in configure'
    from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.4/plugins/kernel_v2/config/vm_provisioner.rb:72:in `call'
    from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.4/plugins/kernel_v2/config/vm_provisioner.rb:72:in `add_config'
    from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.4/plugins/kernel_v2/config/vm.rb:338:in `provision'
    from /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/homestead/vendor/laravel/homestead/scripts/homestead.rb:177:in `block in configure'
    from /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/homestead/vendor/laravel/homestead/scripts/homestead.rb:166:in `each'
    from /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/homestead/vendor/laravel/homestead/scripts/homestead.rb:166:in `configure'
    from /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/homestead/Vagrantfile:30:in `block in <top (required)>'
    from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.4/lib/vagrant/config/v2/loader.rb:37:in `call'
    from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.4/lib/vagrant/config/v2/loader.rb:37:in `load'
    from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.4/lib/vagrant/config/loader.rb:113:in `block (2 levels) in load'
    from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.4/lib/vagrant/config/loader.rb:107:in `each'
    from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.4/lib/vagrant/config/loader.rb:107:in `block in load'
    from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.4/lib/vagrant/config/loader.rb:104:in `each'
    from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.4/lib/vagrant/config/loader.rb:104:in `load'
    from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.4/lib/vagrant/vagrantfile.rb:28:in `initialize'
    from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.4/lib/vagrant/environment.rb:746:in `new'
    from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.4/lib/vagrant/environment.rb:746:in `vagrantfile'
    from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.4/lib/vagrant/environment.rb:492:in `host'
    from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.4/lib/vagrant/environment.rb:214:in `block in action_runner'
    from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.4/lib/vagrant/action/runner.rb:33:in `call'
    from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.4/lib/vagrant/action/runner.rb:33:in `run'
    from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.4/lib/vagrant/environment.rb:479:in `hook'
    from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.4/lib/vagrant/environment.rb:728:in `unload'
    from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.4/bin/vagrant:130:in `ensure in <main>'
    from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.4/bin/vagrant:130:in `<main>'
```

Tried anything I could but still cannot get the box up again.

Also on vagrant global-status, I can see 2 boxes in the same folder:

```
id       name        provider   state    directory                           
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
2727da4  default     virtualbox running  /Users/Leo/Homestead                
6ca3944  co-dev1     virtualbox running  /Users/Leo/vagrant-dev-co           
ae2f475  default     virtualbox running  /Users/Leo/nexuse-vagrant           
83fc055  default     virtualbox running  /Users/Leo/symfony-dev              
bb7c75f  homestead   virtualbox running  /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/homestead 
6634808  homestead-7 virtualbox poweroff /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/homestead
```

tried to destroy 6634808, but got error again:

```
Bins:~ Leo$ vagrant destroy 6634808
/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/homestead/vendor/laravel/homestead/scripts/homestead.rb:4:in `configure': undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)
    from /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/homestead/Vagrantfile:30:in `block in <top (required)>'
    from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.4/lib/vagrant/config/v2/loader.rb:37:in `call'
    from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.4/lib/vagrant/config/v2/loader.rb:37:in `load'
    from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.4/lib/vagrant/config/loader.rb:113:in `block (2 levels) in load'
    from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.4/lib/vagrant/config/loader.rb:107:in `each'
    from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.4/lib/vagrant/config/loader.rb:107:in `block in load'
    from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.4/lib/vagrant/config/loader.rb:104:in `each'
    from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.4/lib/vagrant/config/loader.rb:104:in `load'
    from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.4/lib/vagrant/vagrantfile.rb:28:in `initialize'
    from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.4/lib/vagrant/environment.rb:746:in `new'
    from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.4/lib/vagrant/environment.rb:746:in `vagrantfile'
    from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.4/lib/vagrant/environment.rb:669:in `machine'
    from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.4/lib/vagrant/plugin/v2/command.rb:147:in `block in with_target_vms'
    from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.4/lib/vagrant/plugin/v2/command.rb:201:in `call'
    from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.4/lib/vagrant/plugin/v2/command.rb:201:in `block in with_target_vms'
    from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.4/lib/vagrant/plugin/v2/command.rb:183:in `each'
    from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.4/lib/vagrant/plugin/v2/command.rb:183:in `with_target_vms'
    from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.4/plugins/commands/destroy/command.rb:30:in `execute'
    from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.4/lib/vagrant/cli.rb:42:in `execute'
    from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.4/lib/vagrant/environment.rb:308:in `cli'
    from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.4/bin/vagrant:127:in `<main>'
```

homestead.yaml file is here:

```
---
ip: "192.168.10.10"
memory: 2048
cpus: 1
hostname: homestead
name: homestead
provider: virtualbox

authorize: ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub

keys:
    - ~/.ssh/id_rsa

folders:
    - map: "/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/homestead/code"
      to: "/home/vagrant/Code"

sites:
    - map: 
      to: "/home/vagrant/Code/co-orion/public"
    - map: dev.lara.com
      to: "/home/vagrant/Code/lara/public"
    - map: dev.lara53.com
      to: "/home/vagrant/Code/laravel53/public"
    - map: dev.es.com
      to: "/home/vagrant/Code/es"
    - map: dev.laradminlte.com
      to: "/home/vagrant/Code/laradminlte/public"
    - map: dev.lavalite.com
      to: "/home/vagrant/Code/lavalite/public"
databases:
    - orion

# blackfire:
#     - id: foo
#       token: bar
#       client-id: foo
#       client-token: bar

ports:
#     - send: 50000
#       to: 5000
    - send: 62000
      to: 9200
      protocol: tcp
```

Comment: do you have a `Homestead.yaml` file ?

Comment: Hi  Frédéric Henri! Thanks for your time. Just added the Homestead.yaml file.

Comment: @FrédéricHenri I found out the issue. The sites mapping section has a typo somehow.  Appreciated for your help!  Have a lovely day!

Answer (score 0):

SSH key authentication failure might be the problem

you should edit the Homestead.yaml file. In this file, you can configure the path to your public SSH key, as well as the folders you wish to be shared between your main machine and the Homestead virtual machine.

Don't have an SSH key? On Mac and Linux, you can generally create an SSH key pair using the following command:

```
ssh-keygen -t rsa -C "you@homestead"
```

On Windows, you may install Git and use the Git Bash shell included with Git to issue the command above. Alternatively, you may use PuTTY and PuTTYgen.

Once you have created a SSH key, specify the key's path in the authorize property of your Homestead.yaml file.